# php script enters duplicate data in database

Tags: php, sql-server

I have php script which runs stored procedure from sql server and enters data in table present in database. when i run php script it enters the duplicate date even same data is present in the database.
i need to get rid of these duplicate data.
the stored procedure gives me correct output but it is this php script which is troubling me

```
     while ($obj = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC  ))
{

     if($obj['Bank_Name']!= $obj['Bank_Name_old'])
            {       
            $obj['company_code']; 
            $obj['Account_Code'];
            $obj['Bank_Name']; 
            $obj['Bank_Name_old'];
            $obj['field_name']='Bank Name';

             if($obj['field_name']='Bank Name')
            {   
                $old=$obj['Bank_Name_old'];     
                $new=$obj['Bank_Name']; 
            }
                    $query="insert into vns_db.dbo.client_details_log (company_code,client_id,field_name,original_value,new_value) values ('".$obj['company_code']."',
                            '".$obj['Account_Code']."','".$obj['field_name']."','$old','$new')";    
                            $res = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
                            //$obj['modified_fields']=$obj['field_name'].'|'.addslashes('$old').'|'.addslashes('$new');

                        //  echo $query;
            }   
        if($obj['Bank_AcNo'] != $obj['Bank_AcNo_old'])
            {
                     $obj['company_code']; 
                     $obj['Account_Code'];
                     $obj['Bank_AcNo']; 
                     $obj['Bank_AcNo_old'];
                     $obj['field_name']='Bank account number';

                        if($obj['field_name']='Bank account number')
            {   
                    $old=$obj['Bank_AcNo_old']; 
                    $new=$obj['Bank_AcNo'];         
            }
                     $query="insert into vns_db.dbo.client_details_log (company_code,client_id,field_name,original_value,new_value) values ('".$obj['company_code']."',
                            '".$obj['Account_Code']."','".$obj['field_name']."','$old','$new')"; 
                            $res = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
                            //$obj['modified_fields']=$obj['field_name'].'|'.addslashes('$old').'|'.addslashes('$new');
                            //echo $query;

            }
```

Comment: `if($obj['field_name']='Bank Name')` will always be true, most probably you  want to use `==` there. Same for `if($obj['field_name']='Bank account number')`.

Comment: All lines just containing only one of these: `$obj['company_code'];` are completely useless. They don't do anything.

Comment: It is not the problem.when i run the script it inserts proper data into database. when i again run the script it enters same data.i have 8 different values for above query.when i run it for first time it gives me 8 rows.when run again it gives 16 rows

Comment: I know that's not THE problem, that's why I post it as a comment and not an answer. But it's A problem you have to solve too.

Comment: If you want to prevent duplicate data in subsequent runs you have to either check if the records already exist, add unique keys that prevent duplicate data or store an index of already processed source data and start the next run after that index.

Answer (score 2):

There is a possibility of execution of both if conditions in your loop:

```
if($obj['Bank_Name']!= $obj['Bank_Name_old'])
```

and

```
if($obj['Bank_AcNo'] != $obj['Bank_AcNo_old'])
```

This might run insertion two times
Tryout :)

Comment: It is not the problem.when i run the script it inserts proper data into database. when i again run the script it enters same data.i have 8 different values for above query.when i run it for first time it gives me 8 rows.when run again it gives 16 rows

Answer (score 0):

If both `if($obj['Bank_Name']!= $obj['Bank_Name_old'])` and `if($obj['Bank_AcNo'] != $obj['Bank_AcNo_old'])` will be `true`, two datasets will be added to table `client_details_log`.

If the if statement `if($obj['field_name']='Bank account number')` will be `false`, the variables `$old` and `$new` will not be updated so that the same data will be added to the table twice.

Maybe you have to move your sql queries inside your `if($obj['field_name'] == ...)` statements:

```
if($obj['field_name'] == 'Bank Name')
{
    $old=$obj['Bank_Name_old'];     
    $new=$obj['Bank_Name']; 

    $query="insert into vns_db.dbo.client_details_log (company_code,client_id,field_name,original_value,new_value) values ('".$obj['company_code']."', '".$obj['Account_Code']."','".$obj['field_name']."','$old','$new')";

    $res = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are one or two things that could pose a problem with your code. First, as Devanshu stated you could duplicate (see my recommendation below). Second your if statements are assigning (=) instead of comparing (==). Third, you should try and use functions rather than duplicating code which can make debugging difficult.

Try something like this:

```
function addData()
{
    $query = "insert into vns_db.dbo.client_details_log (company_code,client_id,field_name,original_value,new_value) values ('".$obj['company_code']."',
            '".$obj['Account_Code']."','".$obj['field_name']."','".$old."','".$new."')";    
    return sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
}

while ($obj = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC  ))
{

     if ( ($obj['Bank_Name']!= $obj['Bank_Name_old']) || ($obj['Bank_AcNo'] != $obj['Bank_AcNo_old']) )
    {       
        $obj['company_code']; 
        $obj['Account_Code'];
        $obj['Bank_Name']; 
        $obj['Bank_Name_old'];
        $obj['field_name']='Bank Name';

         if ($obj['field_name']=='Bank Name')
        {   
            $old=$obj['Bank_Name_old'];     
            $new=$obj['Bank_Name']; 
        }

        if ($obj['field_name']=='Bank account number')
        {   
            $old=$obj['Bank_AcNo_old']; 
            $new=$obj['Bank_AcNo'];         
        }       

        $res = addData();
    }   

}
```

Comment: Your "solution" still contains irrelevant code and logical errors. It won't work at all.

Comment: Thanks Gerald, it is only meant to be a guide along with my comments.